# Seaborn kdeplot cumulative not rising to 1 when split by hue

Tags: python, seaborn

Trying to use the sns.kdeplot() and keep running into an issue where the cumulative doesnt rise to one. This seems to predominantly occur when there is a large imbalance in the categories.

Any ideas what might be causing the normalization to not work as intended?

Example:

*Create Sample Data*

```
import pandas as pd # 1.1.0
import numpy as np # 1.18.1
import seaborn as sns # 0.11.1

np.random.seed(42)
sim_data = [[x,np.random.random(),'A' if x < 250 else 'B'] for x in np.arange(0,1000000)]
sim_data = pd.DataFrame(sim_data,columns=['Index','Value','Category'])
```

*Plot Split by Hue (Left Hand Chart)*

```
sns.kdeplot(
  data=sim_data,
  x='Value',
  hue='Category',
  common_norm=False,
  common_grid=True,
  cumulative=True
)
```

*Plot Split by Hue Single Category (Right Hand Chart)*

```
sns.kdeplot(
  data=sim_data[sim_data['Category']=='A'],
  x='Value',
  hue='Category',
  common_norm=False,
  common_grid=True,
  cumulative=True
)
```

[image: Cumulative Distribution Charts with varying number of Categories]

Comment: This appears to be largely driven by the Category A distribution requiring a wider range on the xaxis but it not being taken into account in the adjustment

Comment: Try using `common_grid=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the common_grid = True to common_grid = False seems to resolve above.

Thanks @Trenton